# Android Eclipse Plugin Not Working

Tags: android, eclipse

Hi
Since one year i was not using Eclipse for Android before that it was working fine now i am not able to create Android Application Project while i was trying to create it's not able to identify the Required sdk.
[image]
 In eclipse android sdk manager icon not at all responding , android virtual device manager is giving error like **Location of Android SDK has not been setup in the preference**  eclipse window->preference->Android i checked the sdk location which is fine but it's not able find any target sdk's
[image]
and based on some other questions in stackoverflow i update android sdk manager using commandline. So can any please help me to resolve this error or i has to uninstall and re-install it again
Thanks

Comment: try installing SDK on a differrent location say usr/android-sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi
I tried different ways like check updates in eclipse and updating those which is not worked for me then i manually updated the plugin by following [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html),which solved my problem. I hope this will help others